# Bandwidth usage increased in WordPress 3.5

Tags: performance

I am facing bandwidth issue, for last (2012) whole year bandwidth usage of my WordPress site was 11.66 GB, after updating WordPress to version 3.5 in early January 2013, bandwidth usage for my site in January 2013 is 38.76 GB.

Does anyone have any idea about the cause of this issue?

Comment: This is currently a [guessing game](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/). Please add some facts to make useful answers possible. What is the bandwidth used for?

Comment: well i can see in my cpanel some ip accessing my site more than expected

Comment: Then [inspect that IP address](http://ip.toscho.de/). If it isn’t yours block it for a while. I don’t think this is a WordPress problem.

Comment: one more thing is in Awstats in Cpanel, there is a list of links from external site, for jan-2012 it shows a long list of unprofessional/xxx sites

Answer (score 2):

Based on the information provided its nearly impossible to tell whether or not WordPress is the cause of your problem. However its almost certain that its not.

That amount of bandwidth is highly excessive for it to be contained to a "problem* caused by the WordPress core itself.

You could attempt to inspect the amount of database queries being conducted per-transaction/request but in saying so you should also see some sort of correlation between increased database usage and your site traffic.

In fact inspecting your traffic logs will give you an indication if there has been a spike in traffic and if so, where that increasing traffic is going to (what page/location) within your site structure which may include accessing files directly and not necessarily anything within your WordPress page structure.

I would question your hosting support about this matter as they have the proper tools to analyze this problem.